# Kinect retrieve a portion of image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, kinect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kinect crop image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682447/kinect-crop-image)

Hi I am new to stackoverflow and in kinect.

I'm facing a problem. It would be nice if anyone can give me an example.

Problem: I am using VideoFrameReady to display the camera mode in RGBvideo image control. This image control is height: 600 and width: 800. I want to retrieve just a portion of that image and display it on another image control. I'm using C# language and working in WPF.

```
// This is my kinect VideoFrameReady method
void runtime_VideoFrameReady(object sender, 
                             Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Nui.ImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    PlanarImage image = e.ImageFrame.Image;

    BitmapSource source = BitmapSource.Create(image.Width, image.Height, 96, 96,
                                              PixelFormats.Bgr32, 
                                              null, image.Bits, 
                                              image.Width * image.BytesPerPixel);
    RGBvideo.Source = source; // RGBvideo is image control
} 
// example of the result I want. Retrieve the portion that are surrounded by a box/rectangle.
```

I'm sorry if my question is not clear. I hope that someone can help me with it.