# Kinect 2 crop Image

Tags: c#, kinect

Copy byte array from the kinect 2 is heavy part and I don't need all the image,
I want crop the image when I copy the byte array from the kinect 2.

(Question similar to [kinect 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682447/kinect-crop-image), but for kinect 2)

Answer (score 1):

Answer also similar to [kinect 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682447/kinect-crop-image) :) The logic is the same: get the pixels buffer and use a nested loop to copy to a new image. You might optimize by using array copy functions on a line-per-line basis.

Comment: In kinect 1 I resive the byte array as: `e.ImageFrame.Image[index]`, I didn't find way to do somthing like this without copy first all the byte array. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes. You can use [ColorFrame.LockRawImageBuffer()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.colorframe.lockrawimagebuffer.aspx) method and then read from the returned IBuffer, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh464978.aspx).

Comment: Can you give me example how to use LockRawImageBuffer() to copy relevant byte[]?